# How to built-in run python tox command and test in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tox, vscode-python

I have tox.ini in my project, and I want for running and showing test in visual studio code, using python tox, but I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Update: since June 2021 there **is** a Visual Studio Code extension for tox: [python-tox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=the-compiler.python-tox).

To use:

1. Install the extension
2. Ensure that tox is installed in the base version of Python running on your OS
3. Open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (Cmd-Shift-P on a Mac)
4. Type `tox`
5. Select from one of the available commands (see the extension homepage for details)

Disclaimer: I am not the author of the extension, but kudos **to** the author.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no `tox` extension for VS Code.

I just open the integrated terminal within VS Code and run it.

You can also run any external tool, e.g. `tox` via a so-called task, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks